# How to Access File's VersionData via API Callout in Python

Tags: rest-api, files, python

**tl;dr** - How can one access the returned data from a callout to a ContentVersion.VersionData field value (sObject blob) in Python?

**Background**

As a follow up to [this question's reply](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/300845/download-contentversion-versiondata-in-python/300846#300846), I currently have a python script that makes an API call similar to the example below. The call is successful, but the response does not have a body and the `response.text` is a massive file with many missing ascii keys.

Call example:
`/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/069XXXXXXXXXXXXX/VersionData`

Response:

[image]

The [salesforce documentation on sObject blob data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm) states that the content is returned in binary form, but my attempts to convert from binary to other forms have failed.

**Question**

How can I convert/decode the returned sObject blob data into a usable data type?

Comment: all those diamond-? values indicate a non-UTF-8 character and hence the Blob can't be decoded into anything but must be used as is

Comment: @cropredy that makes sense, but I wonder if that's a result of using `r.text` as opposed to some other property. Maybe that's the only way to access the data but I'm wondering if there's another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find out the issue - rather than accessing the returned data via `request.text`, I used `request.content` which returned a bytes literal string. This opened up many more options for decoding and file writing.

Comment: Good job solving your problem and coming back here with the update