# Error when pulling contentversion data to create file in google drive using python

Tags: contentversion, python, google-drive

I am getting an error when trying to create a file in google drive using the salesforce contentversion data url

```
for (index, row), (index2, row2) in zip(df2.iterrows(),df3.iterrows()):
     
    acid = row['AccountId']
    acname = adict[acid]
    fdname = acname +' - '+ acid
   
    folder_metadata = {
        'name': fdname,
        'mimeType':'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents': ['1-5zP-GutalHIJvS8xpBpe0QuYUqOeAV7']
    }
    fres = service.files().create(body=folder_metadata).execute()
    folderId = fres['id']
    
    fname = row2['Title']
    data = row2['VersionData']
   
    url = data.encode()
    fileurl = url.decode('ascii')
    finurl = 'https://'+ instance + fileurl
    
    print(finurl)
#sample url returned is - https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0689Q0000026HeXQAU/VersionData
    media = requests.get(finurl, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {sf.session_id}'})
    fbody = bytes.decode(media.content)
  
    file_metadata = {
        'name': fname,
        'parents': folderId
    }
    
    service.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=fbody
    ).execute()
```

But I am getting an error

**fbody = bytes.decode(media.content)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte**

Any pointers?
Thanks!

**UPDATE - SOLUTION FOUND**
After several failures, this finally worked

```
media = requests.get(finurl, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {sf.session_id}'})
    fbody = MediaIoBaseUpload(BytesIO(media.content), mimetype='application/octet-stream', resumable=True)
    file_metadata = {
        'name': fname,
        'parents': [folderId]
    }
    
    service.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=fbody
    ).execute()
```

Comment: What is `bytes` and why are you decoding it

Comment: _Is_ the content of this file UTF-8 text data? Even if yes, why do you need to decode it if you're just going to send it to another storage service?

Comment: I was following an example so am not even sure. From your previous comment here you said the link has binary content but I dont know how to pass it to drive https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/300845/download-contentversion-versiondata-in-python
I am actually downloading pdf files.

Comment: When i pass media.content directly to the create method without decode, i get TypeError: media_filename must be str or MediaUpload.

Comment: Thanks David, i found something that worked.

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar issue. Regarding your use case, is this to save PDFs viewed in a web browser to your Google Drive that's integrated to Salesforce?